# Having issues with Region3 in roblox lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I have been trying to work on a Region3 script were when you are in it, it plays a song. But I've come across 2 issues, 1 being it thinks the player is always in it when you the player isn't. And the second being the script runs so fast that it keeps repeating before anything can happen

```
local RegionPart = game.Workspace.RegionArea
local pos1 = RegionPart.Position - (RegionPart.Size / 2)
local pos2 = RegionPart.Position + (RegionPart.Size / 2)
local Region = Region3.new(pos1, pos2) 

while true do 
    wait()
    local burhj = workspace:FindPartsInRegion3(Region, nil, 1000)
        local song = game.Workspace.bb
        song:Play()
        print("THE SCRIPT WORKS!")
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query the objects which are in `Region`, but never used the result and just continued. Loop over `burhj` and check for valid parts.

[In this forum](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-to-detect-if-player-enteredleft-region3/1043070/7) the use of `FindFirstChild` is suggested:

```lua
for i,v in ipairs(burhj) do
    local player = v.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if player then
       print("player is in region: " + player.Parent.Name)
    end
end
```

Alternatively, [you can directly use the player position](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-do-you-check-if-the-player-is-in-certain-area/121163/21), if the player object or position is known:

```lua
local pos = yourPlayer.HumanoidRootPart.Position
local center = region.CFrame
local size = region.Size
if pos.X > center.X - size.X / 2 and pos.X < center.X + size.X / 2 and ... then
   print("player is in region")
end
```

A helper function, if not already present, might be helpful.

For the second problem, set a flag if the player is in the region. Play the sound when the flag was not already set. Unset the flag if you leave the region.

```lua
--here are your vars
local enteredFlag = false
while true do 
    wait()
    if playerIsWithinRegion then --here come whatever approach you chose earlier
        if not enteredFlag then
            enteredFlag = true
            local song = game.Workspace.bb
            song:Play()
            print("THE SCRIPT WORKS!")
        end
    else
        --no player is in the region, lets reset the flag
        enteredFlag  = false
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you add suggested code?

Comment: Done! If the scripts contain errors/deprecated code please let me know.